# Angular Material components fail tests

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-test

I have a Sidenav Menu made in Angular. The component looks like this:

The template:

```
 <mat-toolbar color="primary" [fxLayoutAlign]="(settings.menuType != 'mini') ? 'space-between center' : 'center center'" class="sidenav-header">
    <a mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/" (click)="closeSubMenus()" class="small-logo">Menu</a>
    <a *ngIf="settings.menuType == 'default'" class="logo" routerLink="/" (click)="closeSubMenus()">mEMS</a> 
</mat-toolbar>

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="user-block transition-2" [class.show]="settings.sidenavUserBlock"> 
    <div [fxLayout]="(settings.menuType != 'default') ? 'column' : 'row'" 
         [fxLayoutAlign]="(settings.menuType != 'default') ? 'center center' : 'space-around center'" class="user-info-wrapper">
        <div class="user-info">
            <p class="name"> {{currentUser}}</p>
            <p *ngIf="settings.menuType == 'default'" class="position">Rocket Scientist<br> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="settings.menuType != 'mini'" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" class="w-100 muted-text">
       <a mat-icon-button (click)="logout();" routerLink="/login">
            <mat-icon>power_settings_new</mat-icon>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sidenav-menu-outer" class="sidenav-menu-outer" perfectScrollbar [class.user-block-show]="settings.sidenavUserBlock">    
    <span *ngIf="!menuItems">loading....</span>
    <app-vertical-menu [menuItems]="menuItems" [menuParentId]="0"></app-vertical-menu> 
</div>
```

The actual Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSettings } from '../../../app.settings';
import { Settings } from '../../../app.settings.model';
import { MenuService } from '../menu/menu.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../../auth.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [ MenuService ]
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser: String;
  public userImage= '../assets/img/users/user.jpg';
  public menuItems:Array<any>;
  public settings: Settings;
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public appSettings:AppSettings, public menuService:MenuService,public router:Router,){
      this.settings = this.appSettings.settings; 
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let jwt = localStorage.getItem(AuthService.USER_TOKEN_KEY);
    let jwtData = jwt.split('.')[1]
    let decodedJwtJsonData = window.atob(jwtData)
    let decodedJwtData = JSON.parse(decodedJwtJsonData)
    console.log(decodedJwtData);
    this.currentUser = decodedJwtData.sub;

    this.menuItems = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();
  }
}
```

My test is the default basic one:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SidenavComponent } from './sidenav.component';
import { MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatRippleModule, MatCardModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';

describe('SidenavComponent', () => {
  let component: SidenavComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidenavComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SidenavComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidenavComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Every time I am running this test I am getting these errors because of Material components

```
Can't bind to 'fxLayoutAlign' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-toolbar'.
    1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component and it has 'fxLayoutAlign' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.



    1. If 'app-vertical-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-vertical-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("-block-show]="settings.sidenavUserBlock">
        <span *ngIf="!menuItems">loading....</span>
```

All of the above mentioned coponents I have added into app.module.ts

```
import { MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatRippleModule, MatCardModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and exported them ... so I am a bit lost, I don't understand what I am doing wrong of if I should be importing/exporting these modules differently.

Comment: Surely you need to have `fxLayoutAlign` instead of `[fxLayoutAlign]` in your mat-toolbar. And where is your `app-vertical-menu` component defined?

Comment: You mean where it's defined in the test ? That I might have missed, but it shouldn't return material errors anyway.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to use a selector from which component you have not imported, so it is asking you "where is this component"

Comment: I added the VerticalMenuComponent in the test:  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SidenavComponent, VerticalMenuComponent ]
    }) , but the mat-toolbar errors keep coming up.

Comment: In your posted code you only have `declarations: [ SidenavComponent ]`. You added `<app-vertical-menu [menuItems]="menuItems" [menuParentId]="0"></app-vertical-menu>`, but where does this `app-vertical-menu` selector come from? Just like selectors like `<my-app></my-app>` you need a source component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, your component doesn't understand the `flexLayout` directives because you didn't import it in the test module.

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

---

What you are lacking is the understanding of the test module. Basically, it is used to re-create the context of your component, to be able to set aside the whole dependencies Angular is using in the background.
That's why you need to re-import the modules you are using in your original module that declares your component.

For example, here is one of my test module :

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          CommonModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          MaterialModule,
          FlexLayoutModule,
          RouterTestingModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
          SomeComponent
        ],
        providers: [
          // Some examples of stubs used
          { provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeServiceStub },
          { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
          { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'id': 1 }]) } }
        ],
        schemas: [
          NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
        ]
      });
```

---

Your second error is because your component probably uses the `app-vertical-menu` component, and since you don't want to have that in your unit test, you should use the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` declaration in your testing module.

If you want to write more complex tests, such as integration tests, you can define another test suite with another testing module, that will embark both component (you will have to declare both).

Here is an example :

```
  describe('Integration Test of SomeComponent', () => {
    // fixtures and stuff declaration

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          CommonModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          MaterialModule,
          FlexLayoutModule,
          RouterTestingModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
          SomeComponent,
          OtherComponent // Here the other one is declared
        ],
        providers: [
          { provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeServiceStub }, {
            provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}
          }
        ]
        // No more NO_ERROR_SCHEMA here
      });

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
      componentInstance = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create component', () => {
      expect(componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
    });
  })
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT :** Here is an example of my component that uses the ServiceStub instead of the service. Instead of actually calling **getTheme()** and do the HTTP call, I use the stub that overrides this method and returns static data. This allows to avoid having a full service with the Angular HTTP dependency, which may also have other internal Angular Dependencies and such.

```
// Outside of your test class
export class SomeServiceStub {
  constructor() {}

  getTheme(): Observable<Theme[]> {
    const themes: Theme[] = [
      {
        id: 128,
        code: 'EEE',
        libelle: 'Fake label 1'
      }, {
        id: 119,
        code: 'DDD',
        libelle: 'Fake label 2'
      }
    ];
    return Observable.of(themes);
  }

  // Other services methods to override...
}

// In your testing module :
providers: [
  { provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeServiceStub }, 
  { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
]
```

Comment: It does, a lot. I understand now that these components need all the dependencies when being tested.  

My only problem and misunderstanding ... or better yet lack knowledge of is how to test components independently. 

I don't want to test components that are based on other components and have services in their constructors and so on (integration tests), because as far as I can't tell, if one of the services is down, the component test will fail.  I just want a simple component test, without any routing and so on. This is my first rodeo with Angular and there is a lot i need to figure out.

Comment: That's why you use stubs to test your component. All you need to do is configure a dynamic module that will re-create your component context with dependencies and stuff like that, but you can override those with mock classes and stubs.

That's why in the unit test (1st example), you can see that I use `useClass : SomeServiceStub` that overrides my original service. The aim is to override the methods in that service that would originally make an HTTP call and make them return an Observable that completes instantly.

This way, your "dependency" is actually a class that resolves static data.

Comment: You can do the same for the Router with `RouterTestingModule` from this import : `import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';` so that the only real thing loaded for your test is your component.

Comment: I did add that since I have another test that is passing that is using it, the issue is that after importing everything  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SidenavComponent,VerticalMenuComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, FlexLayoutModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [AppSettings, AuthService],
      schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  })); I only get back a [object ErrorEvent] thrown with nothing else, so I am stuck there :)

Comment: This is probably due to your providers, you are still using the real services, and this chain of dependencies can cause some errors hard to detect like that.
I'm editing my answer to provide a stub example.

Comment: This is linked to this issue in my opinion : https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2852